# jQuery - if div height over 'x', show only content within the visible div, add an image and scroll up to show full div

Tags: jquery

Apologies, I'm very new to jQuery. 
I am trying to apply jQuery to a div which could contain any number of p tags of varying length or none at all.  Depending on the assembled p's this div needs to maintain a height of 45px. If the p's contained therein push the div to be higher than 45px then I need to add an anchor image which users can click allowing the div to slide up and reveal the div's contents.  I've browsed the plugins but can't find anything to cater for this.

```
<div class="SummaryExtras">
<h3><span>h3 Title</span></h3>
<div>
  <p class="Extra">text</p>
  <p class="Extra">text</p>
  <p class="Extra">text</p>
  <p class="Extra">text</p>
  <p class="Extra">text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="SummaryExtrasBottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does a scrollbar work for you?
just apply css style overflow-y:auto; to your container div:

```
<div style="height:45px;overflow-y:auto">
```

If not, try Ariel Flesler's  [ScollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) or [SerialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) plugin